# how to left join a column in access 2007?

Tags: sql, join, ms-access-2007, left-join

I have this query in access 2007:

```
    SELECT Clientes.ID, Clientes.Nombre, Sum(CuentasCorrientes.Debe-CuentasCorrientes.Haber) AS Deuda
FROM Clientes INNER JOIN CuentasCorrientes ON Clientes.ID = CuentasCorrientes.CodCliente
GROUP BY Clientes.ID, Clientes.Nombre, 
HAVING (((Sum([CuentasCorrientes].[Debe]-[CuentasCorrientes].[Haber]))>0))
ORDER BY Clientes.Nombre;
```

This works OK,
Now i need to add the max date from another table that have all the payments. Linked by the Customer ID.
Like This:

```
SELECT Clientes.ID, Clientes.Nombre, Sum(CuentasCorrientes.Debe-CuentasCorrientes.Haber) AS Deuda, Max(Fecha_1.Fecha) AS UltimoPago
FROM CuentasCorrientes AS Fecha_1 INNER JOIN (Clientes INNER JOIN CuentasCorrientes ON Clientes.ID = CuentasCorrientes.CodCliente) ON Fecha_1.CodCliente = Clientes.ID
WHERE (((Fecha_1.TipoPago)<>''))
GROUP BY Clientes.ID, Clientes.Nombre
HAVING (((Sum([CuentasCorrientes].[Debe]-[CuentasCorrientes].[Haber]))>0))
ORDER BY Clientes.Nombre;
```

But when i add this date "UltimoPago", the date is ok! but the field "deudas" (debts) , starts showing wrongs sums (already try using Distinct).

how can i do this with? in softwares like Qlikview iis easy but i need the sql code working in this access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your query and make the JOINS better

```
SELECT Clientes.ID, 
Clientes.Nombre, 
Sum(CuentasCorrientes.Debe-CuentasCorrientes.Haber) AS Deuda, 
Max(Fecha_1.Fecha) AS UltimoPago
FROM CuentasCorrientes AS Fecha_1 
INNER JOIN Clientes ON Fecha_1.CodCliente = Clientes.ID
INNER JOIN CuentasCorrientes ON Clientes.ID = CuentasCorrientes.CodCliente 
WHERE Fecha_1.TipoPago <> ''
GROUP BY Clientes.ID, Clientes.Nombre
HAVING Sum([CuentasCorrientes].[Debe] - [CuentasCorrientes].[Haber] > 0) 
ORDER BY Clientes.Nombre;
```

Comment: it says: 'missing operator in Fecha_1.CodCliente = Clientes.ID 
INNER JOIN CuentasCorrientes ON Clientes.ID = CuentasCorrientes.CodCliente'